# Writing pdf document and storing in specified location with unique name in jframe

Tags: java, swing

Am Trying to write a pdf document and store it in specified location

```
String docname=txt_search.getText();//getting name for document
```

and writing document using

```
PdfWriter writer
        = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(docname));
```

I want to store this in a specified location like `C:/user/(docname)`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not ask the user with a [file chooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)?

Comment: No its not like a file and am not storing anything into database its like creating a new pdf document

Comment: From what I understand about your question, why can't you just contatenate something like `System.getProperty("user.home")` to `docname`? If you want to use a dir other than the user.home, You may first need to check if a directory exists, by creating a new File and checking `exists()` on the file object.

Comment: @peeskillet raises several important points; you may also need to verify permissions. Would `createTempFile()` be apropos?  If your `.pdf` is not a file, what is it?

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"*  Ask a *specific* question, voting to close this one.

Comment: ya i used temp to do that thank you all